# Loop through lnk files with vbs and get their target paths

Tags: for-loop, vbscript

I want to loop through a bunch of files in a specific folder (the files in question being .lnk files). In that loop I what to be able to reference the file path of their target (all folders).

I'm doing this so I can use a script I found to change their icon, that icon being a file inside there target folder all with the same name cover.ico. The script I'm going to use to change the icon is

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

lnkfile = "Path\To\LinkFile.lnk"

Set lnk = sh.CreateShortcut(lnkfile)

lnk.IconLocation = "Path\To\IconFile.ico"

lnk.Save
```

the script to change a lnk icon works I've tested it I just need to get it into a loop.
I also already now how to get the path of the .vbs current directory using this

```
Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sScriptDir = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

so that takes care of geting the file path for the .lnk themselves since I will have the .vbs running in the same path as the .lnk files.

Comment: And your question is? (Hint: "I need this in a loop" is not a question, that's a programming assignment.) What have you tried? What errors do you get? What is your reasoning about your attempts?

Comment: how to make a for loop that loops through files in a folder?

Comment: That's a pretty basic question. Have you tried searching for an answer to that? *"How to loop through files in a folder in VBS?"* seems like a good question for a search engine.

Comment: Start with reviewing the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a vbscript that can extract all targets paths from links located on your desktop :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,objStartFolder,objFSO,objFolder,colFiles
Dim objFile,strFilePath,Lnk
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objStartFolder = Ws.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
  Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
  For Each objFile in colFiles
  strFilePath = objFile.Path
  If Ucase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFilePath)) = "LNK" Then
      Call ExtractTargetPath(strFilePath)
  End If
  Next
'*************************************************************
Sub ExtractTargetPath(Lnk)
set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set Lnk = Ws.Createshortcut(Lnk)
WScript.echo "Link="& DblQuote(Lnk) & vbcrlf &_
"Target="& DblQuote(Lnk.TargetPath)
End Sub
'*************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*************************************************************
```

***Edit : on 19/06/2017 @14:00***

You can also do it with a batch file using this vbscript :

***Extract_Targets_Links.bat***

```
@echo off
Title Extract targets paths from links
Set "LogFile=Links_Targets.txt"
If exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
Set "Desktop=%Userprofile%\Desktop"
Set "All_Users=%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
Set "Current_User=%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
Set "VbsFile=%Tmp%\%~n0.vbs"

> "%VbsFile%" (
    echo Option Explicit
    echo Dim Ws,objStartFolder,objFSO,objFolder,colFiles
    echo Dim objFile,strFilePath,Lnk
    echo Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell"^)
    echo objStartFolder = WSH.Arguments(0^)
    echo Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
    echo Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder^)
    echo Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    echo For Each objFile in colFiles
    echo strFilePath = objFile.Path
    echo   If Ucase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFilePath^)^) = "LNK" Then
    echo       Call ExtractTargetPath(strFilePath^)
    echo   End If
    echo Next
    echo '*************************************************************
    echo Sub ExtractTargetPath(Lnk^)
    echo set Lnk = Ws.Createshortcut(Lnk^)
    echo WScript.echo "Link="^& DblQuote(Lnk^) ^& vbcrlf ^&_
    echo "Target="^& DblQuote(Lnk.TargetPath^) ^& vbcrlf ^&_
    echo String(100,"*"^)
    echo End Sub
    echo '*************************************************************
    echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
    echo     DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr(34^)
    echo End Function
    echo '*************************************************************
)

For %%A in ("%Desktop%" "%All_Users%" "%Current_User%") Do (
    Call :ExtractTarget "%%~A" "%LogFile%"
)

Start "" "%LogFile%" & Exit /b
::******************************************************************************
:ExtractTarget <Folder> <LogFile>
>> %2 (
    echo =====================================================================
    echo                 Links and their targets on %1 
    echo =====================================================================
)
For %%f in (%1) Do (
    CScript /nologo "%VbsFile%" "%%~f" >> %2
)
Exit /b
::******************************************************************************
```